# How to Join SQL Table Content having 2 primary keys?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two SQL Tables in my database

Structure of table1 is ie `customer_classification` is

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_classification` (
>   `sid` int(5) NOT NULL,
>   `customer_id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
>   `classification` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
>   `appendix_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
>   `bill_date` date NOT NULL );
> ```

Structure of table2 is ie `customer_consumption` is

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_consumption` 
>   `sid` int(5) NOT NULL,
>   `customer_id` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
>   `bill_date` date NOT NULL,
>   `reading` float NOT NULL,
>   `consumption` float NOT NULL,
>   `energy_bill` float NOT NULL, 
>   `meter_rent` float NOT NULL,
>   `arrear` float NOT NULL );
> ```

In both tables, primary keys are `customer_id` and `bill_date`, because in a particular month there is only bill corresponding to single customer.

Now, my problem is, I am not able to merge these tables data into one to display the whole record.

I have tried this Sql Query, have a look

```
select co.customer_id, co.reading, co.consumption, cl.classification
from   customer_consumption as co
INNER JOIN customer_classification as cl
   on cl.customer_id = co.customer_id
      and month(cl.bill_date) = month(co.bill_date)
where  month(co.bill_date) = month(now())
```

It is not giving me the accurate result

Comment: What would be the result you want to get and what's the result you get instead? Also, are you using MySQL or Oracle...can't be both, right?

Comment: please provide sample data of your both table and also provide getting result and accepted data

Comment: You will need to include the year as well as the month.

Comment: here is the link to the data in sql tables [csv] format [https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bzm3lRWPbtA9cGlXWjZrNWY5TjA&usp=sharing]

Comment: @RyanVincent I am working on the single year data, so year doesn't bother me right now.

Comment: Please, show us a current query result

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bzm3lRWPbtA9cGlXWjZrNWY5TjA&usp=sharing] here is the table data as well as output data

Comment: No one going to look in google drive. take out some sample data and post in your question.

Comment: Is that a typo, or are the datatypes for customer id really not the same in each table?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that the consumption table has records for each month and the classification record only has records when the classification changes.  If so, you want to get the most recent classification.  And you can do that as:

```
select co.customer_id, co.reading, co.consumption,
       (select cl.classification
        from customer_classification as cl
        where cl.customer_id = co.customer_id and
              cl.bill_date <= co.bill_date
        order by cl.bill_date desc
        limit 1
       ) as classification
from   customer_consumption co
where  month(co.bill_date) = month(now());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL query

```
select co.customer_id, sum(co.reading), sum(co.consumption), cl.classification
from   customer_consumption as co
INNER JOIN customer_classification as cl
   on cl.customer_id = co.customer_id
      and month(cl.bill_date) = month(co.bill_date)
where  month(co.bill_date) = month(now())
group by co.customer_id
```